# vi yank and repeat pasting in a visual selection

Tags: vim

Is it possible to yank some words and paste them in a vi visual selection? Lets say that I select the following words in a column using visual block with ctl-v then yank with y.

```
one
two
three
```

then make a selection and paste them in order to fill it with p

```
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 2):

Before hitting p, perform a visual selection of the area you'd like to replace using shift-v. Then hit p to replace it.

Comment: this pastes the three words in the first three lines and fills the rest lines of selection with spaces!

Comment: Use shift-v instead of ctrl-v. ctrl-v is column based, shift-v is row based.

Comment: ^ although vi would not call it `S-v`, but rather `V` :)